# Preventing scroll by dragging mouse cursor

Tags: html, css, list, scroll

I have a list inside a div which is scrollable horizontally. Everything works great, except for the fact that the user can drag the list vertically using the mouse cursor, displacing the content.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/xy9mnbr2/. Dragging the cursor down on the yellow space causes the layout to break, despite the fact that `overflow-y` is set to `hidden` and there should be no extra space anyway.

HTML:

```
<div id="scrollable-list-outer">
<ul id="scrollable-list">
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul#scrollable-list {
    margin:0;
    float: left;
    right: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(270deg);
    transform: rotate(270deg);
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 200px;
}
ul#scrollable-list li {
    padding: 5%;
}
#scrollable-list-outer {
    margin: 5% 10% 0 10%;
    width: 80%;
    height: 200px;
    float: right;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    background: lightyellow;
}
#scrollable-line {
    width: 80%;
    height: 1px;
    background: #ccc;
    margin: 10px 10% 0 10%;
    float: left;
}
ul#reach-list li {
}
```

Comment: The behaviour is not reproducable in Firefox. When you use chrome you can use mousewheel scrolling in the yellow area; when you are still in scrolling mode and leave the area, the whole chrome tab becomes unusable

Comment: Hm, FF doesn't seem to have an issue with it, only Chrome and Safari. Not sure by the tab? It works great in FF for me. @NicoO

Comment: Try it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/xy9mnbr2/8/